# Parse Error : Invalid Numeric Literal in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have get [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFdTq.png) in my Laravel Application.

Turns out that the error points to the following lines:

```
/* August */    
$augledcrdt=Companyledger::WhereIn('frm_ledger',$ledgerlist)->whereYear('transaction_date',$curyear)->whereMonth('transaction_date',08)->where('company_id',$companyids)->sum('credit_amt');
$augleddebt=Companyledger::WhereIn('frm_ledger',$ledgerlist)->whereYear('transaction_date',$curyear)->whereMonth('transaction_date',08)->where('company_id',$companyids)->sum('debit_amt');

/* September */     
$sepledcrdt=Companyledger::WhereIn('frm_ledger',$ledgerlist)->whereYear('transaction_date',$curyear)->whereMonth('transaction_date',09)->where('company_id',$companyids)->sum('credit_amt');
$sepleddebt=Companyledger::WhereIn('frm_ledger',$ledgerlist)->whereYear('transaction_date',$curyear)->whereMonth('transaction_date',09)->where('company_id',$companyids)->sum('debit_amt');
```

Comment: put '08' instead of only 08

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using PHP 7.0. You can use the following piece of code to do so:

```
$augledcrdt=Companyledger::WhereIn('frm_ledger',$ledgerlist)->whereYear('transaction_date',$curyear)->whereMonth('transaction_date','08')->where('company_id',$companyids)->sum('credit_amt');
$augleddebt=Companyledger::WhereIn('frm_ledger',$ledgerlist)->whereYear('transaction_date',$curyear)->whereMonth('transaction_date','08')->where('company_id',$companyids)->sum('debit_amt');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change `08` to `8` if you're using PHP7:

```
->whereMonth('transaction_date', 8)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.integers